# Try and except with os.chdir

Tags: python

I work from two different computers with the same script. Writing files to my cloud storage \has a slightly different path on both computers. I thought I could use a [try-except](https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/) to simply see which path works (depending on which computer I am using).

I thought I could solve this by doing the following:

```
import os
try:
    os.chdir('C://Users//comp1//Cloud//Data')
except:
    os.chdir('C://Users//comp2//Cloud//Data')
```

However if I run it, I still get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C://Users//comp1//Cloud//Data')
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here, or whether I should perhaps use a different solution.

Comment: Don't use double slashes, those are not a thing. Single `/` should work even on Windows, which normally uses backslash, thanks to Python doing the conversion for you.

Comment: It's either two backslashes or one forward slash.

Comment: When using different networks, typically a hostname test can be used to pre-assign the appropriate path, and forget the expensive try/except all together (in this case).

Comment: You should use the `r` modifier for path strings `r'C:\Users\...'` and construct them normally

Comment: Thank you for all your comments guys. As note, I would like to say that the double forward slashes did/do work, even though they are apparently not correct (and I will stop using them). The issue was a very silly one.  There was another rogue `os.chir` statement in my script that I had missed. The second time I ran the code it was that statement creating the error (because I was working on the wrong computer).

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out. However I'd still recommend using if-else instead of try-except as I have mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72488239/13536496).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As multiple comments have suggested, replace the double forward slashes with one forward slash, or use double backward slashes.

Now I ran your code and it does seem to work, but it depends on the context (is this your entire script?). However you could do better with a if-else statement rather than try-except because the latter is a lot slower first of all, and generally not the best practice.

```
import os

if os.path.isdir('C:/Users/comp1/Cloud/Data'):
    os.chdir('C:/Users/comp1/Cloud/Data')
elif os.path.isdir('C:/Users/comp2/Cloud/Data'):
    os.chdir('C:/Users/comp2/Cloud/Data')
```

If you'd like to stick to try-except and neither directories exist, you could try using nesting your try-except like this:

Edit: Forgot to mention, thanks [@Tzane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14536215/tzane), do not use bare try-except statements.

```
import os

try:
    try:
        os.chdir('C:/Users/comp1/Cloud/Data')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        os.chdir('C:/Users/comp2/Cloud/Data')
except FileNotFoundError:
    # handle the case where neither directory exist
    pass
```

Or to combine the two suggestions:

```
import os

if os.path.isdir('C:/Users/comp1/Cloud/Data'):
    os.chdir('C:/Users/comp1/Cloud/Data')
elif os.path.isdir('C:/Users/comp2/Cloud/Data'):
    os.chdir('C:/Users/comp2/Cloud/Data')
else:
    # handle the case where neither directory exist
    pass
```

Comment: [You shouldn't use bare except statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except)